# Get promise to wait and check again if not resolved first time in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Right now I have my promise wait 2 seconds then resolve the promise. I want my promise to check if the variable has data if it doesn't wait like half a second then check again if the variable has data. Is there a way to set that loop up efficiently? I am fairly new to promises.

My code:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(real);
    }, 2000);
})
```

Want it to be something like this. So I am waiting for the minimal amount of time

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   if(real == 3){
      resolve(real);
   }else{
      setTimeout(function(){
        //repeat promise check
      }, 200);
   }
})
```

Comment: Don't do polling for a value to appear in a variable. Instead, resolve the promise from the code that sets the variable to the value.

Comment: But if you really have to, just `while (real != 3) await delay(2000);`

Answer (score 0):

You can usually find a different pattern that doesn't require polling values — using events or a callback where you set the value. But, if for some reason you must, you *can* keep polling in an interval. Just don't resolve the promise until you have satisfied your requirement. For example:

```js
let real = 0

function waitForValue(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(real == 3){
         resolve(real);
      } else{
         let interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("checking again")
            
            if(real == 3) {
               console.log("value set")
               resolve(real);
               clearInterval(interval)
            }
         }, 500);
      }
   })
}

// set the value in 2 seconds
setTimeout(() => real = 3, 2000)

waitForValue().then(v => console.log("resolved value:", v))
```

You can also do this in an async function with a little more clarity:

```js
let real = 0
let wait = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t))
async function waitForValue(){
   while (real !== 3) {
      console.log("checking")
      await wait(500) 
   }
   console.log("value set")
   return real

}

setTimeout(() => real = 3, 2000)

waitForValue().then(console.log)
```